# Program executable does not run

Tags: go, fish

If I run `go build -o bin/test ./scripts/test.go` I get an executable, but when I try to run it I get

```
Failed to execute process './bin/test'. Reason:
exec: Exec format error
The file './bin/test' is marked as an executable but could not be run by the operating system.
```

scripts/test.go

```
package scripts

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

Comment: Are you running this via `fish` by any chance?

Comment: @msanford yup i am

Comment: Classical non-answer, but I've seen that fish has many issues [running executbles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223/which-shell-interpreter-runs-a-script-with-no-shebang/373294#373294) (see [arch bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/63112) ) and scripts [without shebangs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491419/fish-shell-exec-format-error). If you're able, try from bash _just to see_.

Answer (score 2):

Should be `package main`:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

https://tour.golang.org/welcome

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) for the `go build` command has the details about how this works.

Summary:

- Building "main" packages will output an executable file
- Building a non-main package will output an object (and discard it)
- Building with `-o` will force the command to not discard the output, and save it to the specified file

So basically what you're doing here is building a non-main package, which outputs outputs an object file, not an executable. Normally this is discarded, but due to using the `-o` option you've forced it to output it to a file.

To get an actual executable, you just need to change the package name to `main` (as noted by Steven Penny)