# Cannot execute golang executable after building

Tags: go

I have to preface that I am beginner when it comes to using Go. I have cloned a project that can be found at `https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/common.git`

Before building, the environment variables for `go` are `GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux`.

After cloning the project I navigate to into the directory that has `go` files, that is `command/`, and run the following command `go build -o analyzer`

This outputs a file called `analyzer`. The one I noticed is that I can't execute this file unless I do `chmod +x analyzer`.

When I do execute the that binary I get an error

```
./analyzer: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./analyzer: line 1: `!<arch>'
```

Comment: What is the exact command you're using to run the binary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Program executable does not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680902/program-executable-does-not-run)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That package is not a main package. Only main packages (with the `package main` statement) will build into executable files.

Comment: It's weird, I would have expected `go build` to fail when trying to build a non-main package.

Comment: I frequently use `go build ./...` to ensure every package and subpackage can build, like after I've made a change.

Comment: @ClarkMcCauley: the `build` command docs: _When compiling multiple packages or a single non-main package, build compiles the packages but discards the resulting object, serving only as a check that the packages can be built._

Comment: That's weird though, since OP was able to explicitly have a resulting object written to disk using the `-o` flag. I wonder what it is?

Comment: It’s the compiled go archive that would be used for linking.